# Android WebView call JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, android, web, webview

I using WebView to show this website
http://app.wlojii.com

I want to make control panel in notification bar to play/stop music.

The problem i cant find the function that play/stop the music.

I inspected the button element and tried some variants of functions unsuccessfully (play, play(), player.play()), and i used this method to call the functions:

> mWebView.loadUrl("javascript: ...")

I am not so familiar with JavaScript and web, i need some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pavel
I have added a git repo with the working code https://github.com/premithk/webviewclickeventexample
The problem last time was that `getElementsByClassName` returns an array. So i have changed the code to

```
mWebview.loadUrl("javascript(function({l=document.getElementsByClassName('mejs-playpause-button');
e=document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
e.initEvent('click',true,true);
l[0].dispatchEvent(e);})()");
```

Any ways the code in repo works such that there is a button (native) that will act as play/pause

Comment: wow, its really work,magic, thank you so much very appreciate your help and time!

Comment: another question, is it possible in my case to listen when i click on play button in webview and make changes in notification bar?

Comment: Yes, The idea is to inject an object to the JS part and use that as a bridge to call a function inside the native part. Have updated the git repo reflecting the change. Only thing is that before we inject the event listener we have to make sure the page is fully loaded, so it might take some time. So first thing is to add the interface `mWebview.addJavascriptInterface(new JSInterface(), "jsnativebridge");` Then define the class

Answer (score 1):

Register a Javascriptinterface or use this library.
https://github.com/lzyzsd/JsBridge/blob/master/README.md
The library acts as a bridge between webview and the Java part of the app

Comment: Thanks, but i need find the function name in JavaScript.

Comment: Are you looking for a generic solution or for this particular website?

Comment: this particular website

Comment: A quick check reveals that this website uses http://www.mediaelementjs.com/. So don't think there will be a straight forward play function. All the player functionality is in http://app.wlojii.com/wp-content/themes/pulsetheme/assets/js/player.js. There you could see the event listener for the play button. Search for `$(document).on('click.btn', '.btn-playpause, .btn-queque', function(e){`

Comment: yes i saw it before, but how can i pass triggered it?

Comment: You can trigger a click event with the below function. You can find the button id in chrome and replace.

`webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){"+
    "l=document.getElementById('replacewiththebuttonid');"+
    "e=document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');"+
    "e.initEvent('click',true,true);"+
    "l.dispatchEvent(e);"+
    "})()");`

Also if the button does not have an ID we can even find using the class name getElementsByClassName.

Comment: i have log error : I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatchEvent' of null", source:

Comment: that means l is null from `l=document.getElementById('replacewiththebuttonid');` Did you replace 'replacewiththebuttonid' with your button id?

Comment: seems like no id ,<button type="button" aria-controls="mep_0" title="Play" aria-label="Play"></button>.

Comment: `webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){"+
    "l=document.getElementsByClassName('mejs-playpause-button');"+
    "e=document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');"+
    "e.initEvent('click',true,true);"+
    "l.dispatchEvent(e);"+
    "})()");`
Then try the above code with getElementsByClassName

Comment: oh another error: I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: l.dispatchEvent is not a function", source:  (1)

Comment: Sorry pavel, i will try a sample project tomorrow and see.

Comment: Ok,thank you very much i am very appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, The idea is to inject an object to the JS part and use that as a bridge to call a function inside the native part. Have updated the git repo reflecting the change. Only thing is that before we inject the event listener we have to make sure the page is fully loaded, so it might take some time. So first thing is to add the interface `mWebview.addJavascriptInterface(new JSInterface(), "jsnativebridge");`

Then define the class

`private class JSInterface {
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void playPauseClicked(String string) {
            Log.d("console", "" + string);
        }
    }`

Then wait for page load and add the event listener like below

```
mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                Log.d("console", "" + "loaded");

               mWebview.loadUrl(
                        "javascript:(function() { " +
                                "var ch=document.getElementsByClassName('mejs-playpause-button');" +
                                "ch[0].addEventListener('click', function(){" +
                                "    jsnativebridge.playPauseClicked('Yes');" +
                                "});"+
                                "})()"
                );

            }
        });
```

You can refer the git repo, have added a working demo. 
Cheers

Comment: i done every thing you said, but not working and no log error

Comment: if possible can you post that class here?

Comment: ok i got it in my case ch[0] need to be ch[37] (another website), have you fiver account that i can contact you for help?

Comment: ah! great, don't have a fiver account, honestly hearing about fiver for the first time :)

Comment: i msg you in facebook